# How to get current users email address for Python error reporting?

Tags: python, windows, email

We're currently using a super basic Python script that I found online a while ago to send an error report via HTML from out departmental email address. However, as it currently stands, it sends the email *from* our email address *to* our email address. I'm hoping there might be some way to send the email from the address of the current user. Here's what we've got:

```
def sendMail(sender, recipient, subject, html, text):

import MimeWriter, mimetools, cStringIO
import smtplib
out = cStringIO.StringIO()
htmlin = cStringIO.StringIO(html)
txtin = cStringIO.StringIO(text)

writer = MimeWriter.MimeWriter(out)
writer.addheader("From", sender)
writer.addheader("To", recipient)
writer.addheader("Subject", subject)
writer.addheader("MIME-Version", "1.0")
writer.startmultipartbody("alternative")
writer.flushheaders()

subpart = writer.nextpart()
subpart.addheader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "quoted-printable")
pout = subpart.startbody("text/plain", [("charset", 'us-ascii')])
mimetools.encode(txtin, pout, 'quoted-printable')
txtin.close()

subpart = writer.nextpart()
subpart.addheader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "quoted-printable")

pout = subpart.startbody("text/html", [("charset", 'us-ascii')])
mimetools.encode(htmlin, pout, 'quoted-printable')
htmlin.close()
writer.lastpart()
msg = out.getvalue()
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com',587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login("sample@email.com","sample")
server.sendmail(sender, recipient, msg)
server.quit()
```

Then we're using a simple try/except execfile script to run everything from:

```
try:
execfile('\\\\path.py')
except:
print 'ATTENTION: An error has been detected in a script process.'
traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)

import sys, cgitb
recipient =   
['sample@email.com','sample2@email.com','sample3@email.com','sample4@email.com']
for rec in recipient:
    Utils.sendMail('sample@email.com',
        rec,
        'ATTENTION: An error has been detected in a script process...',
        cgitb.html(sys.exc_info()),
        cgitb.text(sys.exc_info()))
sys.exit()
```

It's here where we define the address we're sending to:

```
 for rec in recipient:
    Utils.sendMail('sample@email.com',
        rec,
        'ATTENTION: An error has been detected in a script process...',
        cgitb.html(sys.exc_info()),
        cgitb.text(sys.exc_info()))
sys.exit()
```

Is there some kind of AD script we can implement here? We've got about 30 people using our processes so whenever an error pops up all we get is an email with the error and no reference to who it belongs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not easy to work with AD in Python, and it's even tougher to do without installing any 3rd party modules.

Would adding the username that ran the script in the email body or subject suffice instead?:

```
import getpass

user = getpass.getuser()
```

Then in the execfile script:

```
Utils.sendMail(
    'sample@email.com',
    rec,
    'ATTENTION: %s has run a script which has errored...' % user,
    cgitb.html(sys.exc_info()),
    cgitb.text(sys.exc_info())
)
```

It is important to note that this should not be used for any legitimate authentication purposes, as it does not protect against user-spoofing and the likes..

Comment: This actually worked perfectly, it's just what we needed! The full user's name would have been great but this works for what we need it to do since we know the last names of everyone on our team.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to group you recipients i.e. you could have a group for engineers, quality assurance, business development, management, etc..
where each group is represented by a list of email addresses.

This way when an error occurs, you may send a human readable email describing the issue to the quality assurance group.

As for the engineers, you may want to send a more technical email that not only contains the human readable error descriptions, but also an additional stack trace. When an engineer is attempting to troubleshoot an error message more, is better.

As for the business development and management group, they probably shouldn't be receiving emails on failures.

hope that helps.

Comment: Why are you using execfile('\\\\path.py') rather than importing path.py??

Comment: Well everyone is a GIS Analyst on our team but only the 3 of us that work with Python are the ones who have access to that specific email address. So only the 3 of us currently receive error message emails, but as it stands we have no clue who they're coming from until they send us a Skype message informing us. 

I used execfile('\\\\path.py') rather than importing it because the .py file is not in the same directory. We have all of our scripts located in a separate drive. The execfile just makes it a bit easier and keeps our folders tidier.

Comment: have you checked the email header? i noticed you provided gmail addresses. in gmail, you can find the more down arrow > show original and it will display all the info related to that email.

Comment: Oh sorry, it's not gmail, I redacted our email addresses and just replaced it with @email.com just for an example. We're all using Outlook Exchange accounts company wide. That's why I was thinking AD might give me what I want. I know that Django has a getuser function but we're writing scripts with the idea that no one will have to install anything on their machines, so Django won't work for us.